# itemized multiplication issue in for loop, python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, multiplication

I am working on a program to calculate the weighted average of multiple lists of weights and grades.  I need to create custom exceptions because not all the data is in the proper format.  I am running into two problems, how do I create helpful exceptions and still run all of the lists and two my itemize_mult variable is throwing an error that 'a' is not defined.

```
def weighted_avg(grades, weights): 

    for b in weights:
        if b < 0: 
            (print("For {}".format(weights), "each weight must be 
greater than zero."))
            raise Exception
        if b > 100: 
            (print("For {}".format(weights), "each weight cannot be 
more than 100."))
            raise Exception
        if sum(weights) != 100: 
            (print("For {},".format(weights), "the sum of the weights 
does not equal 100."))
            raise Exception
    for a in grades: 
        if a in grades != b in weights: 
            (print("For {}{}".format(grades, weights, "the number of 
grades must match the number of weights.")))
            raise Exception
        else: 
            itemized_mult = [a*b for grades, weights in zip(grades, 
    weights)]
            combined_weight_grade = sum(itemized_mult)
            output = combined_weight_grade * 100
            print(output)
            print(itemized_mult)

grades1 = [88,99,100,70]
weights1 = [30, 30, 30, 5]

grades2 = [78, 75, 80, 99]
weights2 = [110, 10, -20, 0]

grades3 = [84, 80, 67, 97]
weights3 = [50, 25, 25]

grades4 = [100, 80, 90, 75]
weights4 = [20, 25, 25, 30]

x =(weighted_avg(grades1, weights1))
y =(weighted_avg(grades2, weights2))
z =(weighted_avg(grades3, weights3))
zzz =(weighted_avg(grades4, weights4))

print("List: ", itemized_mult, "Your weighted grade is: ", x)
print("List: ", itemized_mult, "Your weighted grade is: ", y)
print("List: ", itemized_mult, "Your weighted grade is: ", z)
print("List: ", itemized_mult, "Your weighted grade is: ", zzz)
```

Comment: itemized_mult is not in scope of the print statements, your function will have to return it

Answer (score 1):

When you raise an exception, you can pass in an exception message

```
raise Exception('Put your useful message here')
```

You can create custom exceptions like this

```
class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyException, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.data = data
```

Notice how it also accepts some custom `data` in addition to an exception message.

```
def func():
    raise MyException(50, 'This is the exception message')
```

You can get access to those attributes like this:

```
try:
    func()
except MyException as e:
    print(e.message)
    print(e.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt at cleaning up your code. I have used `assert` widely for simplicity, but you can equally `raise Exception` if desired.

```
def weighted_avg(grades, weights): 

    # overall checks
    assert sum(weights) == 100, "Sum of weights must equal zero: {0}".format(sum(weights))
    assert len(grades) == len(weights), "the number of grades must match the number of weights: {0} vs {1}".format(len(grades), len(weights))

    # specific checks
    for b in weights:    
        assert b >= 0, "Each weight must be greater than zero: {0}".format(b)
        assert b <= 100, "Each weight cannot be more than 100: {0}".format(b)

    # results
    itemized_mult = [a*b for a, b in zip(grades, weights)]
    combined_weight_grade = sum(itemized_mult)
    output = combined_weight_grade / 100

    return itemized_mult, combined_weight_grade, output

grades1, weights1 = [88,99,100,70], [30, 30, 35, 5]
grades2, weights2 = [78, 75, 80, 99], [90, 10, 0, 0]
grades3, weights3 = [84, 80, 67, 97], [50, 25, 25, 0]
grades4, weights4 = [100, 80, 90, 75], [20, 25, 25, 30]

a = weighted_avg(grades1, weights1)
b = weighted_avg(grades2, weights2)
c = weighted_avg(grades3, weights3)
d = weighted_avg(grades4, weights4)

print("List: ", a[0], "Your weighted grade is: ", a[2])
print("List: ", b[0], "Your weighted grade is: ", b[2])
print("List: ", c[0], "Your weighted grade is: ", c[2])
print("List: ", d[0], "Your weighted grade is: ", d[2])
```

Comment: I'm not able to combine the grades and weights manually.  I'm still getting an exception that "a" in itemized_mult is not defined. Can you explain the indexes that you added [0], [2]?

Comment: @JessMatthews, have you really copy-and-pasted my solution above? I see no errors...